# How to get rid of MORE/LESS

Tags: gmail

In my label/Folder is the option for more or less labels. Since I have over a hundred labels, I find it a great nuisance to click every time to get more. I would like to remove the options so that I can continuously scroll.

Answer (score 2):

- all you need to do is to select/grab it with mouse and move up, above **Less**
- and repeat the action until you are satisfied with the result

  [image: 0]